# How does a web browser determine what to do with a resource?

Tags: browser, resources

In the browser's address bar, I can specify a resource using any extension or none, e.g., http://www.something.com/someResource.someExtension. How does the browser determine what to do with this resource? e.g., should the browser parse it as an HTML document, or treat it as some script? Is there a notion of a resource type? Thank you.

P.S. I could not believe what I was thinking! :( (see my flaw in the comment to Luka's answer). How could the browser look at a resource locally! The browser is a client, and the resource resides on the server side. Duh! (I've found myself on this "mental" drug occasionally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP response returned by server typically contains "Content-type: text/html" or similar  line (application/octet-stream, etc).

Here's an example (the easiest way to view similar results is to open firebug's Net tab):

```
Cache-Control   public, max-age=60
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  9334
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8<----------------here's it
Date    Sat, 05 May 2012 20:34:36 GMT
Expires Sat, 05 May 2012 20:35:36 GMT
Last-Modified   Sat, 05 May 2012 20:34:36 GMT
Vary    *
```

Comment: as other answers mention, it's the MIME type after Content-Type.

Comment: Luka, thank you! and wow, I just realized I had a major misunderstanding all along. If it was not for your reference to HTTP response, I would keep thinking the browser first "looks" at the resource to determine if it it something that it can process "locally," (i.e., without sending a request to the server), e.g., rendering an HTML file based on ".htm" extension. Now, I understand that the browser always sends an HTTP request to the server, and processes the HTTP response. 

How refreshing to get a side benefit! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I am as pleased as you to see my response helped you :) When I digged into how things worked I too was like wow now _that's_ how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks at the Mime Type of the document.

HTML pages have the mime type `text/html`, JPEG images have `image/jpeg`

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 0):

It does using MIME types http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type.